# IIS8 MVC5 Use of Class tag blows CPU

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Really puzzled about this. A simple application with a grid rendered in Razor with cells that contain button elements. I notice that each time the page is rendered/re-rendered the CPU of w3wp hikes by 20% until saturated. If I take the "class" attribute off my button it behaves normally.

The offending line is

```
 <button class="testClass">Bumblebee</button>
```

If I take out the class attribute, the cpu behaves normally. Any class attribute (whether the css exists or not) leads to the abberant CPU spike (which never goes down).

I reached this line of markup by a process of elimination, gradually removing async, mongo, Authorize, RequireHttps out of the equation - and was really surprised to be able to remove the problem just by removing the class attribute from a piece of markup ... what gives ?

It doesn't matter if I have the VS.net debugger attached or just run the site without the debugger attached. Sysinternals ProcMon shows IIS w3wp process doing nothing in particular (in fact very little indeed) whilst its whizzing away at 20-30% CPU. I am using VS.net 2013 Express for Web with IIS site set to Default App Pool, Integrated running as LocalSystem.

I've done a lot of web development before but not with Razor so I'm really at a loss to explain this behaviour. Has anyone else seen this before ?

Comment: Turn on Fiddler to see what requests are being issued. Maybe some productivity addin that has inserted script into your page and is now running rampant due to a bug.

Comment: @usr - he's using vs express, addin's are not allowed and don't work.

Comment: Have you installed update 3?

Comment: I seem to recall a bug with the "Browser Link" feature that caused this problem in the release version, it was fixed in a later update, which is why I asked if you've installed the latest update (Update 3)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - I shall try this. Is this Update 3 for Windows 8, IIS or VS.net 2013 Express ? I checked before posting that all my Windows updates were up to date, so I'm guessing you mean VS.net ?

Comment: @usr Fiddler shows no activity. The page has completed rendering and the CPU just never goes down.

Comment: The CPU in w3wp?! That is hard to believe without requests. Attach the debugger and pause it to see what all threads are doing.

Comment: @usr - Indeed - hard to believe. But true. Erik Funkenbush recommended installing VS.net Update 3 which worked and removed the problem. I suspect therefore it was the MVC components installed by VS.net which were the problem.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - post your recommendation for Update 3 as an answer so I can vote it as the Solution

Comment: @PhillipH - It's not MVC, it's Visual Studio itself.  BrowserLink is a feature that allows Visual Studio to live update its view of the page while debugging.  You can read about it here. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx  It's not related to MVC or Razor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was likely related to a known bug in the BrowserLink feature.

Installing the latest Visual Studio Update (Currently Update 3) will likely solve the problem.